# Linux DRM (Direct Rendering Manager) command submission

Tags: linux, gpu, drm

I'm exploring DRM Linux kernel API but the official documentation only explains device initialization and memory buffer management. I can't find anything related to the execution of executable code on the GPU hardware. How DRM handles this subject? There are an abstraction layer or it is device specific?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this pseudo-tutorial](https://github.com/dvdhrm/docs/blob/master/drm-howto/modeset.c#L414) written by someone who’s contributed to the development of DRM, there is no common API for hardware-accelerated graphics, so I strongly doubt they would be any unified API for what you want to do.